# How many types of bar charts are available in ZedGraph?

Tags: c#, zedgraph, bar-chart

How many types of bar charts are available in `ZedGraph`?

And what are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [ZedGraph Codeplex site](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/zedgraph.aspx) (reformatted):

ZedGraph includes bar charting
 capability for

1. vertical and horizontal bar charts,
2. stacked bar charts,
3. percent stacked bar charts,
4. overlay bar charts,
5. error bar charts,
6. high-low bar charts,
7. open-high-low-close bar charts,
8. and Japanese candlestick bar charts